# When did people start to regard "time" as a physical quantity?

Tags: soft-question, time, history

I was trying to figure out how people came to know about time then I realized that people started keeping track of time to know about sunset and sunrise. But I can't figure out how did time came into the physics world. Other physical quantities can be somewhat directly observed by our 5 senses but what caused time to be considered as physical quantity?

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, try [History of Science and Mathematics.](http://hsm.stackexchange.com)

Comment: A way to refine this question might be to ask who first related values of time to values of some other physical quantity. I know Galileo did [experiments rolling objects down inclined ramps](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~dtl/89S/galileoexperiment.html) where he showed that the distance an object rolled was proportional to the time since it was let go from rest, but I'm not sure if there are any earlier examples.

Comment: I wonder if the invention of sundials or other time keeping apparatuses has anything to do with this.

Comment: A physical quantity is related to the measurement of such a quantitiy. Carving a notch into a bone for each day would already pass as time measurement. More refined methods like clocks or counting tree rings or measuring radioactive isotope levels just add precision or larger measurement intervals.

Comment: It's not clear to me the whole "5 senses" thing is accurate either cognitively or historically. Certainly there is a [sense of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense#Time), and philosophers hundreds of years ago (and maybe thousands of years ago; I'm less familiar with the literature) had no problem saying it was natural to perceive the passage of time and to order things in time just as they are located in space.

Comment: I think this is a neurological question, as rather a lot of careful research and testing has shown that the brain is capable of "observing" the passing of time; in fact some surgical anasthetics break this function, so patients wake up disoriented as to the actual time elapsed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about either neurology or anthropology.

Comment: @DanielSank - Not really. Brahe (late 16th century) made amazingly accurate timestamped naked eye astronomical records, but it's important to realize that astronomy was considered to be quite separate from physics until the 17th century. Kepler (early 17th century) was chided for trying to bring physics into astronomy. I'd date the start to the early 17th century with Kepler and Galileo.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Then why do we have a "history" tag?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No not at all neurology I think. I wanted to know what made the notion of  "time" arise in the world of physics.